# Iterating over nested lists while tracking parent/child relationships

Tags: jquery, html

I appreciate you taking the time to consider my problem.  I am creating an interface that allows a user to essentially make a list of categories using UL and LI tags.  I then store this information in a MySQL database via PHP, so it can then be retrieved and maintain formatting.  I have the PHP side worked out, as well as pulling the tree from the database and formatting it.  The part I'm having trouble with is saving the list via a form submission, and passing it to the PHP in a way that can loop through all the data and know the parent/child relationships.

An example of a list could look like:

```
<ul>
<li>FAQ
    <ul>
        <li>Installing SynergiesMOD</li>
        <li>Updating SynergiesMOD</li>
        <li>Mod Not Working</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Characters
    <ul>
        <li>Necromancer
            <ul>
                <li>Moves</li>
                <li>Guides</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Warlock
            <ul>
                <li>Moves</li>
                <li>Guides</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This list is fully editable, so any particular content can be moved, deleted, or new categories added before it is submitted to the PHP code to be parsed and stored in the database.  I am racking my brain and cannot think of a way to loop through the categories while maintaining the familial relationship when passing the data to PHP.  If any of you all have any ideas or suggestions, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't quite described how you were going to edit each item in the list. I suppose I would have done this by having hyperlinks on each item which would contain the IDs of each item, joined by underscores, e.g.

```
1  FAQ
2  Characters

1_1 InstallingSynergiesMOD
1_2 UpdatingSynergiesMOD
1_3 Mod Not Working
2_1 Necromancer
2_2 Warlock

2_1_1 Moves
2_1_2 Guides

2_2_1 Moves
2_2_2 Guides
```

I am assuming that each item in the hierarchy has an associated id.

When you click on the hyperlink, you can show the same hierarchy, but with the list item replaced by a INPUT field with the NAME="x_y". If the Ok button is pressed (or whatever), this will cause the FORM to be submitted with data for a field. You pass the name of the field to get the IDs, and then update your database with the new value. Finally you print out the new list.

Of course, you could do the same using JSON/XML XMLHttpRequest instead of using a FORM.

Comment: I apologize.  The whole interface is done via jQuery, allowing the dragging and sorting of list elements, as well as deleting or adding new categories via a button that would add a new LI to the list.

Comment: No matter - the general point I was showing that you show the hierarchy by including an id from the top of the hierarchy down to the bottom.

Comment: But do I really even need to get into IDs?  I can use jQuery to check if a LI has a child elements, then use $.each to loop through them.  I am unsure about how to format the information as I loop through it in a structured way that I can use in PHP to know the parent/child relationships when storing to the database.

Comment: My feeling about this is that you should edit the hierarchy in steps. Whenever you move, add, or delete an element, you should send a message back to the server which contains all the information that the server should know, e.g. "ADD,(3),New Category" "ADD,(3,1),New Item". This way the server always has data which mirrors what you have on the web page. Of course, this is all speculation - I don't know how you are modelling your lists on your database.

Comment: That's a good idea, Mark.  Perhaps instead of doing it all at once, just do it piece by piece via ajax.  I will give that a shot.  Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Each `li` should have a `nodeId` (perhaps the `id` of the `li`) and then you would need to calculate a `parentNodeId` in javascript, referencing its parent, to maintain a hierarchical relationship

Comment: That is one thought that had occurred to me, but how to store that information and pass it to PHP?